# Watcher doesn't detect imported file change

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, phpstorm

So, i'm building a new project with `SASS` and `Zurb Foundation` framework. I have a `SASS-Compass` watcher installed in my `IDE (PHPStorm)`, to automatically detect changes and recompile everything into assets.

I have a main file, `app.sass`, which imports `_settings.sass`. My problem is, when i change some variable on my `_settings.sass` file, PHPStorm Watcher doesn't know that he needs to recompile my `app.sass`, and i have to do some changes to `app.sass` for it to recompile, so i could see my changes. This is kinda annoying and makes little sense.

My watcher settings are:

```
Program: C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\compass.bat
Arguments: compile C:/Winginx/home/project.local/public_html $UnixSeparators($FilePath$)$
```

So the question is, has anyone thought about this problem, and maybe have a clever workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your file watcher settings

Comment: Sorry, was away for holidays, edited my post

Comment: Screenshot would have been better. In any case: Do you have "Track root files" option checked?

Comment: Yes, i do have this option checked.

Comment: Well .. I have mentioned the most obvious option that could affect such behaviour. Without seeing the whole project structure etc I would not be able to suggest anything good. My only suggestion right now is to directly put path to `app.sass` into file watcher parameters (so it always compiles it instead of individual files). And if you have more than one of such "root files" -- you can create multiple file watchers (if necessary) and use different scopes (files to watch for changes) in each of them. Maybe somebody elase will have better ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, the answer.

As it turns out - and i didn't know this - there are two kinds of imported files in `SASS`. Normal files, and `partials`. The underscore at the beginning of the name of a file shows it's a `partial` and shouldn't be generated into a css file. A simple test shows that while `compass` watcher detects changes in normal imported files and recompiles everything accordingly, it ignores partial changes, and that's why the problem with `_settings.sass` occured.

Hope it helps somebody.